# Java JDBC - Dynamic Scanner on User Input

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jdbc

Im looking to create a scanner that inputs user data into a MySQL database I've created for a fitness application.

I'm up to a point where now I need the scanner to identify how many columns it should input into based on user input.

The user is asked how many sets they want to input into (e.g. 2), and I'm having trouble creating code that asks the user twice the weight and reps they'd like to input.

The difficulty behind this is that the MySQL database has a large amount of sets they can input into (max 10), but I only want to input into those they've actually completed (2 in this case)

I'm a beginner at this & would appreciate any assistance.

Thanks.

Comment: I am a little confused about `the database has a large amount of sets`. What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: Thanks for the response. By this I meant that I've created the table in MySQL to have set 1, set 2, etc up to 10. In each set it has a column for weight and reps.

Answer (score 0):

New one:
Having the columns set_x_weight and set_x_reps for each set is a bit odd and not really best practice.

A new table which is used for referencing the set would be really good.

The new would just have:

- weight
- reps
- exercise_id

and in your old table you only would need an id to better identify the row.

Every set would be added to the new table and you can simply make a SELECT where you filter by the `exersice_id`

---

Old one: I think you need to reconsider your table structure (if possible). I would not make 10 tables (one for each set), but one table which has these columns:

- weight
- reps
- set -> a number which defines in which set this row belongs to

This way it is also easily extendable.
There are probably columns missing, like a date or something to distinguish the rows better.

But when having only one table you don't have to dynamically insert into different ones.

Comment: My current database is laid out with the following headings: Date_Created, Program_Name, Excercise_Name, Total_Sets, Set_1_Weight, Set_1_Reps, Set_2_Weight, etc. up to Set 10. Apologies if I stated there's a table per set. The issue with this is that I only want to scanner query amount of sets input by the user in 'Total_Sets'

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I may require the other columns for internal purposes, as I'm aiming to separate programs (SELECT specific program) and refer to progress over time with the Date_Created column.